# Laravel redirected you too many times error

Tags: laravel

I am trying to implement a simple role-based authentication system in Laravel 7, where I have an additional field on user table named 'role' of integer type, which can have two values - 0 for general users and 5 for the admins.

Any logged in user should be able to access the '/railway' page. Only admins should be able to access the '/admin' page. Admins should also be able to access the '/railway' page.

I am following this article and getting **'too many redirect'** error: https://dev.to/kaperskyguru/multiple-role-based-authentication-in-laravel-30pc

**Edit:**

Sorry forgot to mention!

Everything is working perfectly for the non-admin users. They are being redirected to the '/railway' page after logging in alright, and also being redirected to this page if they try to access the '/admin page'.

The error is happening for the admins only. It is redirecting them to the '/admin' page after logging in alright, but showing the 'too many redirection' error. But admins can access the '/railway' page which is perfect.

**Edit-3**
I've added this on a git repository, if anyone is interested to reproduce the issue: https://github.com/rawhasan/laravel-auth-bug.git

Here is what I've done so far:

**web.php**

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Auth::routes();

Route::get('/railway', 'RailwayController@index')->name('railway');
Route::get('/admin', 'AdminController@index')->name('admin')->middleware('admin');
```

**Middleware Admin.php**

```
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Auth;
use Closure;

class Admin
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
      if (!Auth::check()) {
          return redirect()->route('login');
      }

      if (Auth::user()->role == 0) {
        return redirect()->route('railway');
      }

      if (Auth::user()->role == 5) {
        return redirect()->route('admin');
      }
    }
}
```

**Kernel.php**

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
    'auth' => \App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
    'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
    'bindings' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
    'cache.headers' => \Illuminate\Http\Middleware\SetCacheHeaders::class,
    'can' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authorize::class,
    'guest' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
    'password.confirm' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\RequirePassword::class,
    'signed' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ValidateSignature::class,
    'throttle' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class,
    'verified' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\EnsureEmailIsVerified::class,

    'admin' => \App\Http\Middleware\Admin::class,
];
```

**HomeController.php**

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class HomeController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }

    public function index()
    {
        return view('railway');
    }
}
```

**AdminController.php**

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class AdminController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        return view('admin.admin');
    }
}
```

**Edit - 2**

I also have this on the **LoginController.php**

```
use Auth; 

class LoginController extends Controller
{
    use AuthenticatesUsers;

    protected $redirectTo;
    public function redirectTo() {
      if (Auth::user()->role = 5) {
        $this->redirectTo = '/admin';
        return $this->redirectTo;

      } else {
        $this->redirectTo = '/railway';
        return $this->redirectTo;
      }
    }

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
    }
}
```

Any help sorting out the issue would be appreciated!

Comment: I saw you found the solution, so for anyone looking at this later you have to know that: 1) **ALWAYS** create tests for your code, it would have shown instantly... 2) When you use custom `Middlewares`, always add `return $next($request);`... 3) If you are going to redirect or similar, check that you are not redirecting to the same route, it is pretty obvious here... If you still need that, write another if asking if the current URL is not the same as the one you are going to redirect...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed this with the help from another source. Removed the following code from the Admin Middleware and it worked perfectly:

```
if (Auth::user()->role == 5) {
    return redirect()->route('admin');
}
```

Since I am redirecting the admins from the loginController, this redirect from the middleware was making the conflict.

I've also kept this code in **web.php** as suggested by Leo:

```
Route::middleware(['auth'])->group(function () {
  Route::get('/railway', 'RailwayController@index')->name('railway');
  Route::get('/admin', 'AdminController@index')->name('admin')->middleware('admin');
});
```

Thanks for the answers everyone!

Answer (score 0):

So in both user roles it requires authentication which means you could wrap your routes under default laravel `auth` middleware for that:

```
Route::middleware(['auth'])->group(function () {
    Route::get('/railway', 'RailwayController@index')->name('railway');
    Route::get('/admin', 'AdminController@index')->name('admin')->middleware('admin');
});
```

And your middleware should look something like:

```
use Auth;
use Closure;

class Admin
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
      if (Auth::user()->role == 0) {
        return redirect()->route('railway');
      }

      if (Auth::user()->role == 5) {
        return redirect()->route('admin');
      }
      return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I've put the first part in **web.php** like this:

`Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Auth::routes();

Route::middleware(['auth'])->group(function () {
  Route::get('/railway', 'RailwayController@index')->name('railway');
  Route::get('/admin', 'AdminController@index')->name('admin')->middleware('admin');
});`

And changed the rest in Admin middleware. But still the same issue. Am I doing it right?

Comment: Please check my second edit on the post. Forgot to mention the LoginController.php code.

Comment: You are still having `return redirect()->route('admin');` and that means, in the same route, it will redirect to the same route, for ever...

Answer (score 0):

Include the following value in config/admin.php file in the end of auth key. after  'remember' key.

```
// Redirect to the specified URI when user is not authorized.
        
'redirect_to' => 'auth/login',

        // The URIs that should be excluded from authorization.
        'excepts' => [
            'auth/login',
            'auth/logout',
            '_handle_action_',
            'auth/forgot-password',
            'auth/reset-password'
        ],
```